# embed a bash script into the raspian for desktop background

Tags: linux, bash, debian, raspbian

I want to change the default raspbian desktop background into something else. I managed to change the splash screen but i also want to change the desktop. My splash code is like following with help from [here](http://www.raspberry-projects.com/pi/pi-operating-systems/raspbian/custom-boot-up-screen)

```
do_start () {

/usr/bin/fbi -T 1 -noverbose -a /etc/splash.png    
exit 0
}

case "$1" in
  start|"")
   do_start
;;
 restart|reload|force-reload)
echo "Error: argument '$1' not supported" >&2
exit 3
;;
stop)
# No-op
;;
status)
exit 0
;;
*)
echo "Usage: asplashscreen [start|stop]" >&2
exit 3
;;
esac

:
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

edit: also i want to know that how the code works for displaying the background of the desktop while booting the system.